# How to increase the border lines width in plot.gam with multiple plots

Tags: r, plot, width, border, gam

Dear StackOverflow users,

I need to increase the border line width of my multiple GAM plots. I tried to use `box(lwd=3)`,but it only worked in the last figure. So my question is how to increase the border line width of every figure.

Here are my codes

```
Gam_AF_species <- gam(Species.AF ~ s(SST) + s(SBT, k=3) + s(Salinity) + 
                      s(Primary.productivity), data = Data)
par(mfrow = c(1,4))
plot.gam(Gam_AF_species, ylab="", xlab="", cex.lab = 1.5, cex.axis= 1.5, 
         cex.main = 3, lwd = 3, lwd.tick = 3)
box(lwd=3)
```

[image: GAM plot]

I also tried not to use `par(mfrow=c(1,4)`, then the figures will out one by one, and I did succeed to increase the border line width of every figure. However, I have over 30 figures need to plot, so this way is not efficiency. Hope you can have suggestions for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to plot each panel separately; your call to `box(lwd = 3)` only comes *after* the final plot has been produced and as such it can only affect that final plot.

To draw the individual panels separately I would use the `select` argument to `plot.gam()` to chose which smooth I wanted to draw.

This is most easily done by creating a quick wrapper function that combines your call to `plot.gam()` *and* the call to `box()` that you want.

A wrapper function might look like this

```
my_plot_fun <- function(smooth) {
  plot(m, select = smooth,
       ylab="", xlab="", cex.lab = 1.5, cex.axis= 1.5, 
       cex.main = 3, lwd = 3)
  box(lwd = 3)
}
```

where all the options are hard-coded, even the model to plot from, and the only think we pass in as an argument is which smooth to draw via an argument `smooth` that we pass to `select` in the `plot.gam()` call.

Then I would use a simple `for` loop to call the wrapper function to plot each smooth in turn.

Here is a full example of how to do this:

```
library('mgcv')

# simulate some data
set.seed(1)
df <- gamSim(1)

# fit the GAM
m <- gam(y ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3), data = df, method = "REML")

# wrapper function for the plot you want
my_plot_fun <- function(smooth) {
  plot(m, select = smooth,
       ylab="", xlab="", cex.lab = 1.5, cex.axis= 1.5, 
       cex.main = 3, lwd = 3)
  box(lwd = 3)
}

# set up the plot to have 1 row and 4 columns
layout(matrix(1:4, ncol = 4))

# loop over the indices 1, 2, 3, 4 to plot each smooth in turn
for (i in seq_len(4)) {
  my_plot_fun(i)
}

# reset the device
layout(1)
```

You could replace the last bit with a `par(mfrow)` call as in

```
# set up the plot to have 1 row and 4 columns
op <- par(mfrow = c(1,4))

# loop over the indices 1, 2, 3, 4 to plot each smooth in turn
for (i in seq_len(4)) {
  my_plot_fun(i)
}

# reset the device
par(op)
```